# How to cleanly install OpenPose?

Tags: python, openpose

I recently needed to work on visual computing, and I went through OpenPose, which looks like a promising tool.
GitHub link to [OpenPose by CMU Perceptual Computing Lab](https://github.com/CMU-Perceptual-Computing-Lab/openpose)

As I'm working on a Windows 10 and developing with Python 3.7.5 (I use other libraries that require `Python<3.8`), I followed [the instruction given for Windows](https://github.com/CMU-Perceptual-Computing-Lab/openpose/blob/master/doc/installation/0_index.md#windows-portable-demo).
So at first, I used the "lazy way": just download the [pre-built version v1.7.0](https://github.com/CMU-Perceptual-Computing-Lab/openpose/releases/tag/v1.7.0), extract it, and execute the `model/getBaseModels.bat` script and everything went fine. I can even run the examples from the `examples` directory.

But the condition is to execute python in this directory, because in the source code of the *.py (which works fine, again), we can find this code:

```py
sys.path.append(dir_path + '/../bin/python/openpose/Release');
os.environ['PATH']  = os.environ['PATH'] + ';' + dir_path + '/../x64/Release;' +  dir_path + '/../bin;'
import pyopenpose as op
```

Instead of a simple and clear
`import pyopenpose as op`
(And I find it strange that even the examples are using a workaround)

The reason is simply that in the folder `..\bin`we find about 90 DLL and in `..\bin\python\openpose\Release\` we find those 3 files:

- pyopenpose.cp37-win_amd64.pyd
- pyopenpose.exp
- pyopenpose.lib

To be sure, I copied one script in a completely different folder, copied also the DLL and the 3 last files. In this case, if I run `import pyopenpose` with python, I get no error but I cannot run the example scripts (for example, `module 'pyopenpose' has no attribute 'WrapperPython'`).
But I don't want to have to include all the 90 DLL for each project I make.

So I guess if all of these files were stored in the Python installation directory, like any package installed by `pip`, I could import all this with a simple `import pyopenpose`.

**So my question is: What is the good way to install the `pyopenpose` package once we've downloaded it?**

---

Additional information: by "curiosity", I also tried to go build the project with CMake, but, of course, the result is the same. I don't know much about CMake, but I thought that the issue could be bypassed by changing some parameters, like turning off the `BUILD_SHARED_LIBS` for example. But that wasn't very smart...

---

Additional question: I have to also install it on the Ubuntu I have at work, and I have the same problem. Would the solution be the same?